# Symfony sfForm password (required and compare)

Tags: php, symfony1

In symfony. . . my form looks like this

```
<?php

class ChangeMyPasswordForm extends sfForm {

    const PASSWORD_REQUIRED_MSG = "We could not update your password. Your password can not be blank. Please enter at least one character for a password.";

    protected static $labels = array(
            'password' => 'Your Password',
        'confirm'  => 'Re-enter Password',
    );

    public function configure()
    {   
        $this->setWidgets(array(
           'password'  => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array()),
             'confirm' => new sfWidgetFormInputPassword(array()),
        ));

        $this->setValidators(array(
            'password' => new sfValidatorPass(),
             'confirm' => new sfValidatorPass(),
        ));

        $this->validatorSchema->setOption('allow_extra_fields', true); 

        $this->mergePostValidator(
            new sfValidatorSchemaCompare('password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::IDENTICAL, 
                'confirm', array(), array(
                    'invalid'=>'Passwords do not match. Please try again.'
                )
            )
        );

        $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorString());
        $this->widgetSchema->setLabels(self::$labels);
    }
}
```

in my controller

```
public function executeMyAccountPassword(sfRequest $request) {
      $this->form = new ChangeMyPasswordForm();
      $this->validated=$request->getParameter('validated');

      $this->form->bind(array(
              'password' => $request->getParameter('password'),
              'confirm'  => $request->getParameter('confirm'),
      ));

      if ($request->isMethod('post')) {

          if ($this->form->isValid()) {
              $this->validated = true;

              // get player object
              $player = $this->getUser()->getProfile();
              $player->setPassword($request->getParameter('password'));
          }
      }
```

I'm trying to add a validator so the password field cannot be blank. I tried modifying

```
$this->setValidators(array('password'=>new sfValidatorString('required'=>'Please enter a password')));
```

But all then the form threw an error even when data was not posted. can anyone show me a proper example of how to validate two matched password fields and ensure that fields are not left blank (after form submission). Thanks !!

Comment: What version of symfony are you using? 1.4?

Comment: Also, what error did you get?

Comment: Yessir . . . 1.4 Was not getting an error.  It would render the form with the error message 'Passwords do not match. Please try again.' It's the right message, I just need it run that validator after the form is posted.

Comment: Ah, thats the controller, not the form class. Can you post the part of your controller where you check the form?

Comment: Just a little point. You have wrong definition of that validator.
Enabling validations are the first array param and messages are second.
You have to set sfValidatorString(array('required'=>true/false), array('required' => 'your require message')).

Check sfValidatorBase::__construct() docs: http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/sfValidatorBase#method___construct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a second error. Move the binding a few lines down, under the if. Meaning you should do the binding with the **posted** values

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) 
{
  $this->form->bind(array(
    'password' => $request->getParameter('password'),
    'confirm'  => $request->getParameter('confirm'),
  ));

  ... etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on your $this-setValidators. Your missing a few parentheses:

`$this->setValidators(array('password'=>new sfValidatorString('required'=>'Please enter a password')));`

Comment: sorry bout that - must've been a type when I wrote the post - editing it now. When I add this line in, the form spits out the error message as soon as it's rendered. -of course the field is blank, the form was just rendered, and the user hasn't entered anything yet.